# Form filling - Set underscores as placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form in html and css, in the form there are several input fields with patterns (like e-mail and postalcode)
Is it possible to set a pattern using stripes?
In the Netherlands there are postalcodes like this: 4953 JV

So this is what i want:
4x _, space, 2x _

Then you will get this: ____ __

When you fill it in, the stripes with a letter above will dissapear: 49__ __

**Here is my code:**

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="7" pattern="[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?[a-zA-Z]{2}" placeholder="bv. 4194 JV" onchange="showLocation();" name="pcodeklant" />
```

Comment: Please post the code which you have tried. Check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have this, but it hasn't got anything like the stripes yet...<input type="text" maxlength="7" pattern="[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?[a-zA-Z]{2}" placeholder="bv. 4194 JV" onchange="showLocation();" name="pcodeklant"/>

Comment: @Pugazh Here above is the code